# How to specify download location for videos downloaded through youtube-dl?

Tags: python-2.7, automation, youtube-dl

I am trying to write a python script for downloading videos fixing the format and download location for all videos.

This works, when download location is not specified.

```
import youtube_dl
link='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_Bwg-dyOHI'
opts=['-f 22',link]
youtube_dl.main(opts)
```

this gives error ,when download location is added.Kindly correct if any changes to be made.

```
import youtube_dl
link='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_Bwg-dyOHI'
opts=['-f 22','-o "D:Temp/video.mp4"' ,link]
youtube_dl.main(opts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.chdir`:

```
import youtube_dl
import os

os.chdir('/path/')

link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_Bwg-dyOHI'
opts = ['-f 22',link]
youtube_dl.main(opts)
```

Comment: Here , I cant give a custom name to video file. Any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\%(title)s.%(ext)s',
}
```

Also, `opts` should be a dictionary.